# Label whenever string starts with "RT"

Tags: php, regex

Having a lot of tweets in a database, I want to replace the RT in "RT @username: ...rest of tweet" with [RT], but obviously only if the "RT" stands at the beginning of the tweet. (function should be case-insensitive)

So: input would be for example

```
RT @username I'm having one jolly good time!!
RT @username RT @username this is fun
I am not using RT as a label - I use my own "retweet" label :P
rt @name here rt is lowercase
```

Output:

```
[RT] @username I'm having one jolly good time!!
[RT] @username RT @username this is fun
I am not using RT as a label - I use my own "retweet" label :P (no changes)
[RT] @name here rt is lowercase
```

Is this a job for regex or regular php? Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this with a regex:

```
$result = preg_replace("/^RT/uim", "[RT]", $searchText);
```

If your input string is not multiline, you can remove the `m`.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a job regular expressions are capable of.

```
/^RT\s*@[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,15}/i
```

This pattern matches the 'RT' tag, in any case sensitivity, plus looks for a following `@twitter_username`. This was my reference for matching a twitter username: http://kagan.mactane.org/blog/2009/09/22/what-characters-are-allowed-in-twitter-usernames/

Answer (score 0):

No PHP necessary. Do it directly in mySQL in one step.

```
UPDATE
  tweet_table
SET
  tweet_text = '[RT] ' +  SUBSTRING(tweet_text, 4)
WHERE
  SUBSTRING(tweet_text, 1, 3) = 'RT '
```